# How to store and read values in cache using Symfony and RedisAdapter?

Tags: php, caching, redis, symfony

I am trying to store some values on cache the first time I load a page. This is the code I am using:

```
$cached_items = [
    'main_nav'   => $main_nav,
    'sub_nav'    => $sub_nav,
    'footer_nav' => $footer_nav,
    'view_as'    => $view_as,
];

$redisConnection = new Client('tcp://redis:6379');
$cache           = new RedisAdapter($redisConnection);
$menu            = $cache->getItem('mmi_menus');

if ($menu->isHit()) {
    return $menu->get();
} else {
    $menu->set($cached_items);
    $cache->save($menu);
}
```

This caching is being done from a non Symfony controller - let's say it's a standalone file.

First problem with the code above,

- the `else` condition is reach out all the time and I think it should not be since values are stored. (check [here](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/vdGoI4Vx8ryS1~cWltcYGV5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=))

Second problem, having this function in a Symfony controller:

```
public function GenerateMenuItemsAction()
{
    $redisConnection = new Client('tcp://redis:6379');
    $cache           = new RedisAdapter($redisConnection);
    $menu            = $cache->getItem('mmi_menus');

    if ($menu->isHit()) {
        return $this->render(
            'CommonBundle:Layout:menu.html.twig',
            ['menu' => $menu->get()]
        );
    }
}
```

`$menu->isHit()` is null so all the time I am getting this exception from Symfony:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add
>   a return statement somewhere in your controller?").

**Update**

I am not using any TTL afaik maybe somehow a default one is setup but this is how the section looks like on the `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: "redis://%redis_host%"
        pools:
            cache.pool1:
                public: true
```

What I am missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you setting cache ttl?

Comment: @mdma I am not, see the update on the OP

Comment: somehow strange that you define redis cache in config.yml but instantiate it with 'new' in your classes. it looks to me you aren't using the configured one but a new one every time - and for those it could be that you don't have a correct ttl defined.

Comment: @LBA I think that could help I mean how I should instantiate the cache if I have configured at `config.yml`? So far the issue is connectivity between the containers (is a docker-compose stack) as far as symfony logs shows but your suggestion is interesting, could you leave me an example of recommended usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my config.yml looks like that:

```
framework:
  cache:
    system: cache.adapter.apcu
    default_redis_provider: redis://%redis_password%@%redis_host%:%redis_port%
    pools:
        redis_pool:
            adapter: cache.adapter.redis
            public: true
            default_lifetime: 0
            provider: cache.default_redis_provider
```

So I can easily (in my Controller) do something like:

```
$this->get('redis_pool')->getItem('myitem');
```

Or you can inject 'redis_pool' as an argument to a Service.

I don't need any 'new' or extra Connection information/configuration - anything is done in config.yml and available as a Service across the application.